# Move Next Node Back Function

Tags: c++, pointers, dll

So I'm trying to write a function for the DLL class called `MoveNextToBack`. The purpose of the function is to move a node's next node to the back of the list. Here's what I have so far, but I don't think it's complete:

```
void DLL::MoveNextToBack(Node *N){

    // If N's next node is the end already, return
    if(N->Next == Tail)
        return;

    // Change N's Next pointer to the one after N's current Next
    N->Next = N->Next->Next;

    // Change N's Next Next's Previous pointer to point to N
    N->Next->Next->Prev = N;

    // Move N to the end
    N->Next->Next = Tail;
    N->Next->Prev = Tail->Prev;

}
```

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: By doing the 2 operations after the return statement, you have just lost the node you are trying to move to the back

Comment: So I should move it to the back first?

Comment: You should first create a node that points to it; then do those two operations

Comment: `Node tmp = N->Next;`?

Comment: Yes, but should be `Node *tmp = N->Next`

Comment: Okay, then after that everything looks good?

Comment: Should be good, however I will post an answer in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
void DLL::MoveNextToBack(Node *N){

    // If N's next node is the end already, return
    if(N == NULL || N->Next == NULL || N->Next == Tail)
        return;

    //Pointer to the next node
    Node *tmp = N->Next

    //Point to the next, next node
    Node *pmt = N->Next->Next;

    // Change N's Next pointer to the one after N's current Next
    N->Next = pmt;

    // Change N's Next Next's Previous pointer to point to N
    if (pmt != NULL)
        pmt->Prev = N;

    // Move tmp to the end
    tmp->Prev = Tail;
    tmp->Next = Tail->Next;
    Tail->Next = tmp;
    Tail = tmp;
}
```